# Kendo UI MultiSelect not firing change event

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI MultiSelect widget working great, except for one little hiccup: I can't get the change event to fire! I can verify this with Kendo UI Inspector in Chrome 44.0.2403.125 m, as the other events I'm capturing show up in the Event Log while the change event doesn't.

My code:

```
$('#multiselect').kendoMultiSelect({
    change: function () {
        alert('Selection changed');
    },
    dataBound: function () {
        // working code
    },
    dataSource: {
        data: pppData,
        pageSize: 40,
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    CourseId: { field: 'CourseId' },
                    CourseName: { field: 'CourseName' }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    dataTextField: 'CourseName',
    dataValueField: 'CourseId',
    filter: 'contains',
    index: 0,
    itemHeight: 29,
    select: function (e) {
        // working code
    },
    template: '<div class="ellipsize">#= CourseId # - #= CourseName #</div>',
    virtual: true
});
```

MTIA :-)

UPDATE: I have narrowed the problem down to the `virtual` attribute being the culprit...if I remove that and `pageSize` from the MultiSelect's options, everything works as expected, although there is a 3 - 5 second lag the first time the user clicks on the MultiSelect, as it loads the 3,945 records in my data set. Does anyone know a way that I can get around this, without breaking the change event?

Comment: It should work, see [this dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@joaosimoes/EMUzO)